# .NET 6.0 request pipeline issue with custom AuthenticationHandler

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, request-pipeline

I am implementing a mixed authentication mode for my ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API / website. Assuming enabled in the config, the initiator of the HTTP request is free to choose between Basic (for machine clients) and challenge-based authentication (for human users) and we dynamically select the right `AuthenticationHandler` based on the authentication header of the HTTP request.

The user visits the Login page, fills the credentials, clicks "Login".
The dynamic selection of challenge-based handler and the authentication works fine. The issue appears later down in the request pipeline. Should my authentication handler return `AuthenticationResult.Success(ticket)`, then map the request to the `/Login` page fails, the `Login.OnPost()` method never gets hit, the HTTP `StatusCode` is set to 400.

The interesting part is, that should my authentication handler return `AuthenticationResult.Failed()`, then routing to the `Login.OnPost()` succeeds.

I built custom middleware that I injected every single place in the request pipeline to watch when the `StatusCode` flips from 200 to 400. It happens at the very bottom after the last delegate (which is `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages()`)

I have hardcoded returning `AuthenticationResult.Failed()` and `Authentication.Success()` in my custom authentication handler to exclude any other factors from the client side.

Comment: you are now giving a very general description about your code and your issue, and it's really hard to give a solution or action plan for troubleshooting via what you provided...